# Get path to jamfile directory from id in boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: key, bjam, boost-build, b2

In my jamroot I have

```
use-project /myproject : $(TOP)/path/to/jamfile/dir/of/my/project ;
```

`use-project` is documented [here](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.tutorial.libs).

Let's say `myproject` defines a library `mylib`

I can then do in a jamfile:

```
lib myotherlib : $(SRC)
                 /myproject//mylib<link>shared
                 ;
```

instead of:

```
lib myotherlib : $(SRC)
                 relative/path/to/jamfile/dir/of/my/project//mylib<link>shared
                 ;
```

But how can I programmatically get the path that the id `/myproject` points to, i.e. `$(TOP)/path/to/jamfile/dir/of/my/project` ?

This could be useful for various reasons:

- not have to define ids for subprojects of "myproject" (i.e. jamfiles in subdirectories of $(TOP)/path/to/jamfile/dir/of/my/project)
- share some resources files

Answer (score 0):

Here is one function that allows that:

```
rule get_path_for_id ( id )
{
    import project ;
    local jamfile_for_id = [ project.find $(id) : . ] ;
    return [ project.attribute $(jamfile_for_id) location ] ;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
myproject_dir = [ get_path_for_id /myproject ] ;
lib myotherlib : $(SRC)
                 $(myproject_dir)//mylib<link>shared
                 ;
```

(which is just an example, the id would be better here, obviously).

Note: I found no clean way to avoid an intermediary variable, only the ugly:

```
import string ;
lib myotherlib : $(SRC)
                 [ string.join [ get_path_for_id /myproject ] //mylib<link>shared ]
                 ;
```